# Какую модель нейронной сети выбрать для решения задачи

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, распознавание

Нейронные сети начал изучать недавно и для решения конкретной задачи. Но ввиду большое числа нейронных сетей и моего неглубокого их понимания - прошу помощи в выборе наиболее подходящей модели.

**Суть задачи:**
На вход подаются строки ограниченной длинны допустим не более 200 символов.
Каждый символ соответственно можно представить в виде utf-кода. Так же изначально каждый символ соответствует одному из 4 возможных типов:

`1 - rus
2 - eng
3 - num
4 - sym`

**Например:**

```
Сальник 20-1701210 42х68х10х15,5 хвостовика

1111111433433333334331331331334343333333333
```

Обучащая выборка показывает финальное состояние строки, в которой присутсвуют уже другие типы:

```
4 - sym 
5 - word
6 - code
7 - size 

Сальник 20-1701210 42х68х10х15,5 хвостовика

5555555466666666664777777777777745555555555
```

Т.е. в качестве входа имеем набор параметров:

```
[{utfCode, type}, {utfCode, type}, {utfCode, type}...]
```

И в качестве выхода имеем такой же набор, но уже с другими типами.

**UPD**

Детальное пояснение:

Идея заключается в том чтобы распарсить строки содержащие технические характеристики, такие как код и размер.

На вход подается не просто строка из типов, и наборы **[тип,код символа]**.

Например для "**Болт 20*50**" входные и выходные данные должны выглядеть так:

```
[char: Б, code: 1041, type: rus] -> word
[char: о, code: 1086, type: rus] -> word
[char: л, code: 1083, type: rus] -> word
[char: т, code: 1090, type: rus] -> word
[char:  , code: 32, type: sym] -> sym
[char: 2, code: 50, type: num] -> size
[char: 0, code: 48, type: num] -> size
[char: *, code: 42, type: sym] -> size
[char: 5, code: 53, type: num] -> size
[char: 0, code: 48, type: num] -> size
```

Comment: Вы сейчас решаете не задачу распознавания, а задачу подготовки данных к подаче в сеть. Например, как аналог, это перевод  ч/б изображения в вектор нулей и единиц.Поэтому, сформулируйте конечную задачу, тогда можно будет дать совет по архитектуре ИНС

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev Нет как раз в первой части приведен пример подготовки данных, а дальше как раз изложено, что на примере входной строки где каждому символу соответствует заданный тип необходима такая модель, которая присвоит каждому символу новый тип, в соответствии с его положением в строке и предыдущим типом.

Comment: То как вы преобразовали данные в первой части будет, по-моему, только мешать. После такого преобразования уже не отличить дефис от пробела или запятой, а это в вашей задаче имеет важный семантический смысл. Вы можете привести больше (разнообразных) примеров входных данных и пояснить что вы хотите получить в итоге (не список типов для каждого символа - по-моему, это промежуточная цель)?

Comment: @MaxU не не не, я не хочу скрывать сами символы чисто типами, я хочу передавать в качестве данных и тип символа и его код в utf. Так я смогу не потерять смысловую составляющую о том - дефис это или точка. Тогда возможно возникнет вопрос - зачем тогда вообще типы вводить, можно было бы по кодам, но тут идея дополнительной связности символов, если они принадлежат к одному типу и идут друг за другом. Пример обязательно сейчас приведу!

Comment: @MaxU добавил пример, надеюсь станет понятнее)

Comment: @MaxU _не список типов для каждого символа_ - как раз именно список типов мне и требуется. но для их определения мне нужно чтобы учитывался код символа, его принадлежность к начальному типу и положение в строке относительно других символов.

Comment: А зачем вам переносить алгоритмичную работу на метод ИНС? ИНС стоит использовать тогда, когда паттерны не являются четкими/явными/тривиальными(нужное подчеркнуть). Я, если честно, до конца не понимаю смысл тако финта ушами

Comment: @Vladimir Afanasyev в этом и проблема. Я пытался эту задачу решить паттернами. У меня получилось порядка 400 паттернов и то они не покрывают всех возможных случаев. Пришлось подключать кучу словарей (единиц измерений, ключевых слов, модификаторов, производителей и т.д. и т.п.). В целом если еще 200-300 паттернов добавить, то в теории да, я смогу закрыть все возможные случаи в той выборке данных на которой я тестирую. Но это определенно крайне не рационально, и качество распознавания с помощью паттернов на текущий момент очень низкое (из-за качества данных).

Comment: @Vladimir Afanasyev поэтому и хочу попробовать ИНС. Задача то по сути для нейронных сетей вполне подходящая и решаемая, насколько я могу судить.

Comment: @DenisRoss, для того чтобы нормально обучить НС вам понадобится немаленький набор правильно __размеченных__ данных - у вас есть такой дата сет?

Comment: @MaxU да, безусловно, иначе бы и смысла не было во всей этой затее)

Comment: @DenisRoss, можете выложить обучающую выборку на какой-нибудь файлообменник, чтобы можно было поиграться с разными моделями?

Comment: @MaxU я её еще не готовил, она в текущем варианте представляет из себя результаты обработки паттернами (то от чего я хочу уйти) и там блочная структура данных а не символьная. Вот как это выглядит сейчас: [ссылка](https://ibb.co/eADXUo)

Comment: @MaxU хотелось в начале понять насколько все же реально решить данную задачу нейронными сетями, прежде чем тратить время на подготовку всех данных в нужную структуру)

Comment: @DenisRoss, в теории вроде бы должно получиться, на практике - надо пробовать ;) Поэтому я и спросил про обучающую выборку...

Comment: @MaxU какой минимальный объем будет приемлемым? Чтобы не мучатся со всеми записями. Так то я понимаю что чем больше тем лучше, но подготовка всех данных может прилично времени занять,а хотелось бы для тестов не тратить много времени)

Comment: @DenisRoss, для начала было бы неплохо показать 20-30 различных вариантов входных данных, чтобы было понятно "насколько все запущено"...

Comment: @MaxU это не проблема, но боюсь смогу уже только завтра. Если есть возможность - можете почту оставить или ссылку на вк - чтобы было проще связаться?

Comment: [Вот пример НС для похожей задачи из курса "Sequence Models" специализации "deeplearning.ai" на `coursera.org`](https://github.com/fanghao6666/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/blob/master/notebook/Neural%20machine%20translation%20with%20attention.ipynb). Предупреждаю - модель не из простых - чтобы понять как работает `Attention mechanism` возможно понадобиться немало времени...

Comment: @MaxU Благодарю! Буду разбираться!